# Google Drive Back Up Issue over BackUps Folder

Tags: java, android, google-drive-api, realm, android-backup-service

I want to upload the local database of my Android Application which includes Realm File, Video Folder, Image Folder. It is similar to WhatsApp APP as i need to upload the data on drive to restore it when user want to switch the phone.

I want it to back up the same way as WhatsApp i.e. the **backups** section of **Google Drive**

I already tried using V3 API of to achieve [https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-sdk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lePou.jpg) this functionality but not able to upload anything inside **BACKUPs** folder of Google Drive.

Screenshot for the location where I would like to upload the file, I was able to upload over google drive but not inside **BACKUPs** folder.

[image]

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static int RQ_GOOGLE_SIGN_IN = 210;
    public static int PICK_IMAGE = 21110;
    private final String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();
    File myFile;
    private GoogleAccountCredential credential;
    private Drive service;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE);
    }
    private void googleAuth() {
        credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(this, Arrays.asList(DriveScopes.DRIVE, DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE, DriveScopes.DRIVE_APPDATA));
        startActivityForResult(credential.newChooseAccountIntent(), RQ_GOOGLE_SIGN_IN);
    }
    private Drive getDriveService(GoogleAccountCredential credential) {
        return new Drive.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
                new GsonFactory(), credential).build();
    }
    @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            String selectedFilePath = FilePath.getPath(this, uri);
            myFile = new File(selectedFilePath);
            googleAuth();
        }
        if (requestCode == RQ_GOOGLE_SIGN_IN && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            String accountName = data
                    .getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
            if (accountName != null) {
                credential.setSelectedAccountName(accountName);
                service = getDriveService(credential);
            }
            new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                    com.google.api.services.drive.model.File fileMetadata = new com.google.api.services.drive.model.File();
                    fileMetadata.setName("myimage");
                    fileMetadata.setParents(Collections.singletonList("appDataFolder"));
                    File filePath = new File(myFile.getPath());
                    FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("image/png", filePath);
                    com.google.api.services.drive.model.File file = null;
                    try {
                        file = service.files().create(fileMetadata, mediaContent)
                                .setFields("id")
                                .execute();
                    } catch (UserRecoverableAuthIOException e) {
                        startActivityForResult(e.getIntent(), RQ_GOOGLE_SIGN_IN);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground: " + file.getId());
                    return null;
                }
            }.execute();
        }
    }
}
```